# There exists $2n-1$ pairs $(a_i, a_j)$ s.t. $a_i+a_j\geq 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a_1, a_2,..., a_{2n}\in \mathbb {R} $ s.t. $a_1+a_2+...+a_{2n}=0$. Show that there exists $2n-1$ pairs  $(a_i, a_j)$ s.t. $a_i+a_j\geq 0$.

My idea: I consider that $a_1,..., a_k\geq 0$ and $a_{k+1},..., a_{2n}<0$(I put them the sign minus).

Then there are $\frac {k (k-1)}{2} $ pairs. Also $a_1+...a_k=a_{k+1}+...+a_{2n} $. But I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

*Motivation:* There are
$$
 \binom{2n}{2} = (2n-1)n
$$
pairs $(a_i, a_j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le 2n$. One can arrange the corresponding sums $a_i + a_j$ in $2n-1$ rows with $n$ entries in per row, so that in each row the entries add up to $a_1 + \ldots + a_{2n} = 0$.

Then every row must have at least one non-negative entry, that makes $2n-1$ sums $a_i + a_j \ge 0$, and the statement is proved.

*Examples:*

$n=2$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 + a_2 &           & a_3+a_4 \\
a_1 + a_3 & a_2 + a_4 \\
a_1 + a_4 & a_2 + a_3
\end{array}
$$

$n=3$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_1 + a_2 &           & a_3 + a_4 &           & a_5 + a_6 \\
a_1 + a_3 & a_2 + a_5 &           & a_4 + a_6 \\
a_1 + a_4 & a_2 + a_6 & a_3 + a_5 \\
a_1 + a_5 & a_2 + a_4 & a_3 + a_6 \\
a_1 + a_6 & a_2 + a_3 &           & a_4 + a_5
\end{array}
$$

*Proof of the general case:* (With the great help of Batominovski!)

Consider the complete graph $K_{2n}$ with vertices $1, \ldots, 2n$. According to [Wikipedia: Graph factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization), it has a “1-factorization”, i.e. the edges can be partitioned into disjoint “1-factors” or “perfect matchings.”

Each perfect matching consists of $n$ edges without common vertices
$$
 (i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2), \ldots , (i_n, j_n)
$$
and since the sum of all $a_k$ is zero, there must be (at least) one vertex $(i_k, j_k)$ such that $a_{i_k} + a_{j_k} \ge 0$.

The total number of edges in $K_{2n}$ is $\binom{2n}{2} = (2n-1)n$, so that the factorization consists of $2n-1$ perfect matches, and we have indeed $2n-1$ distinct vertices $(i_k, j_k)$ with  $a_{i_k} + a_{j_k} \ge 0$.

Comment: Your observation is point on.  First, remove $n$ independent edges (i.e., no two removed edges share a common vertex) from the complete graph $K_{2n}$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$.  Call the resulting graph $G_1$, and let $P$ denote the set of removed edges.  Then, $G_1$ is Eulerian, and we can remove a $(2n)$-cycle $C_1$ from $G_1$, resulting in $G_2$.  Continue to do this until you decompose $K_{2n}$ as a disjoint union of $C_1$, $C_2$, $\ldots$, $C_{n-1}$, and $P$.  Each $C_i$ can be decomposed into two disjoint perfect pairings $P_i^1$ and $P_i^2$.

Comment: Then, if $\big\{\{i_1,j_1\},\{i_2,j_2\},\ldots,\{i_n,j_n\}\big\}$ is a perfect pairing on $K_{2n}$, then you have a $$\left\{a_{i_1}+a_{j_1},a_{i_2}+a_{j_2},\ldots,a_{i_n}+a_{j_n}\right\}\,.$$  The proof is now finished.

Comment: @Batominovski: Unfortunately, graph theory is not my area of expertise :) – I suggest that you post  an answer.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow, I am going to bed.  But if you want to cooperate my idea into your answer to make it complete, then that'd be great.  So I don't have to type it up myself.  Plus, the proof is pretty much your idea.

Comment: @Batominovski: I have tried to incorporate your information into the answer. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: This looks great!  Thank you for a complete answer.